# Get value out of numpy array view boundaries

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a view into part of numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.arange(10)
view  = array[4:8]
```

Can I access element to the left (in memory) of first view element, using only view identifier?
[image]

Comment: If your array is referencing the indices of [4:8] you should be able to access it with view[0] index over the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view` keeps a reference to `array` in the [base](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.base.html) attribute. `view.base` is `array`.

Thus, you could access this identifier by calling `left_element = view.base[3]`.

If you don't know the offset of 4 that generated the view in this case, you may be able to reconstruct it by looking at raw pointers in the [array interface](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.interface.html), or simply the [byte_bounds](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.byte_bounds.html#numpy.byte_bounds). This is easily done in this tiny example, but might be harder to get right when non-contiguous multidimensional arrays are in play, or in a different orders.

For your 1D example you could use:

```
offset_bytes = np.byte_bounds(view)[0] - np.byte_bounds(view.base)[0]
offset = offset_bytes // view.strides[0]
left_element = view.base[offset - 1]
```